# In using React JS, why does setState fail to update chart values on Button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My page is written in React JS and contains a jS chart. What am attempting to do is have the chart data change based off of a value that is entered via a text box. The graph should display the new results upon clicking a button. The problem am witnessing is that the graph fails to update when the button is clicked.

My set up consist of the following:
1) In a construction, I set the state of the text-value to 10

```
constructor(){
       super();
       this.state = {
        chartData:{},
        cfmRateFactor: 10,
       };
   }
```

2) I have a function where I uses setState to change the  text-box value

```
fncRandom() {
var maxNumber = 5;
this.setState({cfmRateFactor: Math.random() * maxNumber});
```

}

3) Then inside the **getChartData** function is where I add the new state to the default values of the chart.

```
getChartData() {
    var adjJanTotalKWh = 700000 + this.state.cfmRateFactor;
    var adjFebTotalKWh = 617594 + this.state.cfmRateFactor;
    var adjMarTotalKWh = 181045 + this.state.cfmRateFactor;
    var adjAprTotalKWh = 153060 + this.state.cfmRateFactor;
    var adjMayTotalKWh = 106519 + this.state.cfmRateFactor;
    var adjJunTotalKWh = 105162 + this.state.cfmRateFactor;
    var adjJulTotalKWh = 95072 + this.state.cfmRateFactor;
}
```

The full code:
https://codepen.io/washingtonpr07/pen/bMxWyJ?editors=0010#0

...could I get some help with this please?

Comment: `this.setState()` takes a javascript object. `{cfmRateFactor: this.state.cfmRateFactor = Math.random() * maxNumber}` is not a JS object. Maybe you meant `{cfmRateFactor: Math.random() * maxNumber}`?

Comment: I try that (see edit above), but still the same result; it appears the problem passing the cfmRateFactor value from the fncRandom function to the getChartData function. Any other suggestions

Comment: Do the graph and data appear when the component initially mounts?

Comment: @ Pat Mellon, ...Yes,  both the graphs and data appears on the initial mount. Any suggestions?

Comment: `setState` doesn't always immediately update things: [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Reading that might be helpful. Also, you might consider changing fncRandom() to something like ` fncRandom() {`
    `var startingNumber = this.state.cfmRateFactor;`
   ` var maxNumber = startingNumber + Math.random() * 5;`
    `this.setState({cfmRateFactor: maxNumber});}`
  That might help getting the values saved in state.

Comment: Also, in the example you provided your change function that's supposed to get the user's input looks off. The state that you show in your example doesn't have a place to store the user input. If your state included `value: ''` then you could do something like `this.setState({value: e.target.value});` Not sure if that's related to this issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be `e.currentTarget.value`, not `e.target.value`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `onclick` to `onClick`:

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.fncRandom.bind(this)}>Update Chart</button>
```